# Regex isn't parsing the email body correctly

Tags: c#, regex, email

I have my regex codes to parse this out on my email body.

```
Building: {building number} // new line
Level: {level of building} // new line
Phase: {phase or room number} // new line
Request: {your request}
```

Example:

```
Building: 1
Level: 2
Phase: 20
Request: Get 4 chairs
```

Here's my regex:

```
string re1 = "(Building)"; // Word 1
string re2 = "(:)";        // Any Single Character 1
string re3 = "(\\s+)";     // White Space 1
string re4 = "(\\d)";      // Any Single Digit 1
string re5 = "(\\n)";      // White Space 2
string re6 = "(Level)";    // Word 2
string re7 = "(:)";        // Any Single Character 2
string re8 = "(\\s+)";     // White Space 3
string re9 = "(\\d)";      // Any Single Digit 2
string re10 = "(\\n)";     // White Space 4
string re11 = "(Phase)";   // Word 3
string re12 = "(:)";       // Any Single Character 3
string re13 = "(\\s+)";    // White Space 5
string re14 = "(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
string re15 = "(\\n)";     // White Space 6
string re16 = "(Request)"; // Word 4
string re17 = "(:)";       // Any Single Character 4
string re18 = "(\\s+)";    // White Space 7
string re19 = "(\\s+)";    // Match Any

Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6 + re7 + re8 + re9 + re10 + re11 + re12 + re13 + re14 + re15 + re16 + re17 + re18 + re19, RegexOptions.Multiline);

Match m = r.Match(body);

if (m.Success) {
    blah blah blah
} else {
    blah blah
}
```

The problem is even if the format (email body) is correct, it's still not matching my regex and it's not storing on my database.

Is my regex correct?

Comment: the last part re19 - surely you want .* not \\s+

Comment: on top of that, use `RegexOptions.Singleline` instead of Multiline

Comment: You can also use `"(\\s)"` instead of `"(\\n)"` for `White Space 2,4,6` ;).

Comment: And why over complicate things like that? It could be written as `Regex r = new Regex("Building:\\s*\\d\nLevel:\\s*\\d\nPhase:\\s*\\d+\nRequest:\\s.*", RegexOptions.Singleline");` which is basically the same as your complex multi line statement ;) (it doesn't capture **everything** though - guess you really don't want that)

Comment: @ClasG I need the value to store it in the database.

Comment: Still, you can't really need to capture everything - including constants like `Building`... can you? And what are you saving in DB? The regex text itself or the values of the fields? If the latter `Building:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*Level:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*Phase:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*Request:\\s([^\\n]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline` probably is more suitable. It captures the values of each lines field.

Comment: @ClasG Yes, I need to capture the values of the fields. And how can I call those values to the database? Like this, cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building", d1);

Comment: Already solved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are some useless complications that prevents from matching. This answer sums up the suggestions made in the comments to try to improve your regexp.

Then, your regexp is making groups of everything because of the parenthesis. While this is not especially problematic, this is totally useless. If you want though, you could match the values passed in the mail, but this is totally optional. This would be the result regex:

```
Building:\s(\d)\s*Level:\s(\d)\s*Phase:\s(\d+)\s*Request:\s(.*)
```

You can try it here, at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kS8hC6/1) and see the grouping results of the regular expression.

If you want to retrieve the values, you can use a `Matcher`.
The result java code, with escaped characters, would be the following:

```
String regex = "Building:\\s(\\d)\\s*Level:\\s(\\d)\\s*Phase:\\s(\\d+)\\s*Request:\\s(.*)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // There could be exceptions here at runtime if values in the mail
    // are not numbers, handle it any way you want
    Integer building = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
    Integer level = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
    Integer phase = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));
    String request = matcher.group(4);
}
```

I would STRONGLY recommend to be very careful with the last input to avoid any kind of SQL injection.

Comment: I copied your regex pattern but I got this error: parsing "Building:\s(\d)\s*Level:\s(\d)\s*(Phase:\s(\d+)\s*Request:\s(.*)" - Not enough )'s.

Comment: Yep, there was a typo, it's fixed

Comment: Thank you! It's already storing in my database. I appreciate your help!